# Can't log in after trying to set environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, gradle

So I added a file called gradle.sh to /etc/profile.d/ that had the following lines:

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/home/gradle/
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
```

I restarted my machine, so that it would pick up the changes. Now when I go to log in on any user, I get a flash of a black screen with some text (that I don't have time to read), and it goes immediately back to the login screen.

I was using this tutorial to get through setting up my gradle install,
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks right to me. Possibly the trailing slash in `/home/gradle/` should be dropped, but I can't see how it would cause the login to fail.

You know what, there is a pending change to the lightdm package that will help prevent problems like this. If you are on 14.04 or 14.10, I would suggest that you install the lightdm version in [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gunnarhj/+archive/ubuntu/misc). It's a fix of [bug #678421](https://launchpad.net/bugs/678421).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm in an old install of ubuntu, and I may just take the opportunity to do an upgrade since I can't login now anyway. Will do the update and post back if I'm still having problems. I can't install any packages atm, since I can't login.

Comment: @ScubaSteve: Something you can do when you are on the login screen is pressing **Ctrl+Alt+F1**, which opens a console. From there you can log in with your username and password. You could for instance look for error messages in the file `~/.xsession-errors`.

Comment: So I've removed the syntax error from the file, and it all looks good now, but the problem is still occurring. What am I doing wrong here with this environment variable?

Comment: Syntax is as follows:

export GRADLE_HOME = /home/sean/gradle-2.1
export PATH = $PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin

Comment: @ScubaSteve: The spaces before and after the '=' character. It should be `export GRADLE_HOME=/home/sean/gradle-2.1` etc. There are no such spaces in the code you show us in your question.

Comment: I actually resolved this by editing the PATH file directly. Seems  to have worked :D